# Python xarray's open_mfdataset works in an unexpected way

Tags: netcdf, python-datetime, netcdf4, python-xarray

I have 365 daily netCDF files for the year 1980. These files are located in a folder that has data from multiple years (1979-2013).

When I open the 1980 files using,

```
files  = glob.glob("/mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/Subset/data_1980*")
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(files, engine="netcdf4")
```

The time stamp seems to be incorrect. When I print out the time, I get the following:

```
ds.time.sortby("time")
Out[28]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 3286)>
array(['1979-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', '1979-01-07T03:00:00.000000000',
       '1979-01-07T06:00:00.000000000', ..., '2013-12-23T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-12-23T21:00:00.000000000', '2013-12-24T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-07 1979-01-07T03:00:00 ...
Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    axis:           T
```

To check if the other files in the folder are being read, I changed the contents of the folder (i.e. I removed the 2012 files), but I still get the same time series as before. I am not sure what is wrong!

```
Out[29]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 3286)>
array(['1979-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', '1979-01-07T03:00:00.000000000',
       '1979-01-07T06:00:00.000000000', ..., '2013-12-23T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2013-12-23T21:00:00.000000000', '2013-12-24T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-07 1979-01-07T03:00:00 ...
Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    axis:           T
```

The NetCDF data has the metadata as follows (using ncdump -h):

```
svimal@lettenmaierlab06:/mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/Subset$ ncdump -h data_19800530.nc
netcdf data_19800530 {
dimensions:
    lon = 503 ;
    lat = 170 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
variables:
    double lon(lon) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
    double lat(lat) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "hours since 1999-5-16 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    float air_temp(time, lat, lon) ;
        air_temp:long_name = "air temperuature (C)" ;
        air_temp:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        air_temp:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float vp(time, lat, lon) ;
        vp:long_name = "vapor pressure (kPa)" ;
        vp:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        vp:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float pressure(time, lat, lon) ;
        pressure:long_name = "pressure (kPa)" ;
        pressure:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        pressure:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float windspd(time, lat, lon) ;
        windspd:long_name = "wind (m/s)" ;
        windspd:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        windspd:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float shortwave(time, lat, lon) ;
        shortwave:long_name = "downward shortwave (W/m^2)" ;
        shortwave:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        shortwave:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float longwave(time, lat, lon) ;
        longwave:long_name = "downward longwave (W/m^2)" ;
        longwave:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        longwave:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;
    float precip(time, lat, lon) ;
        precip:long_name = "precipitation (mm/hr)" ;
        precip:_FillValue = -9.99e+08f ;
        precip:missing_value = -9.99e+08f ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version ?? (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
        :history = "Tue Mar 20 14:36:48 2018: ncea -d lat,41.375,83.625 -d lon,181.375,306.875 /mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/data_19800530.nc /mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/Subset/data_19800530.nc\n",
            "Tue Mar 20 14:36:44 2018: cdo -f nc import_binary /mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/CFSR-LAND_Global_0.25deg_data_changed.ctl /mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/data_19800530.nc" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.7.0 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
        :NCO = "\"4.5.4\"" ;
        :nco_openmp_thread_number = 1 ;
}
```

The time attribute says

```
time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
```

I am not sure what this means, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you *sure* that your use of `glob.glob()` is only returning netCDF files with times in 1980?

I would suggest a spot-check with an explicit loop (skipping `open_mfdataset`):

```
files = glob.glob("/mnt/nfs/home/solomon/Data/CFSR/NetCDFs_1979-2013/Subset/data_1980*")
for path in files:
    ds = xarray.open_dataset(path, engine="netcdf4")
    print(path, ds.time.values)
```

Side note: it's best to pass the glob string directly into `open_mfdataset()` rather than explicitly calling `glob.glob()`. It is a little more succinct, and xarray also calls `sorted()` on glob strings that it parses, rather than relying on the platform specific order of the list returned by `glob.glob()`.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @shoyer! The issue was with my files. The file names that start with '1980' contained data from other years. It happened because I modified the same input control file to create multiple netcdf files in parallel, using:

```
cdo -f nc import_binary CFSR-LAND_Global_0.25deg_data_changed.ctl data_19800530.nc
```

Making unique ctl files per parallel thread fixed the issue.